# Streamlit Logic to toggle between text and Upload Document

Tags: python, streamlit

I am stuck for hours in trying to figure out a user flow in streamlit.

What I want is below:

1. A default home page with text or upload document option and since text option is default selection, it also shows a text area and a Submit Button underneath that

[image]

2. Then if a user chooses Upload document,then a sidebar opens up with file_uploader. The radio selection should still remain but the text and submit button is cleared.

[image]

3. If a user uploads a file, then the main page radio button should also clear as I would then show something else based on what is uploaded by user.

[image]

4. If a user clears the file in side bar, then the side bar should get cleared, and we should be back to first default screen on page as Point 1 above.

I am able to get to step 3 above, but 4 is giving me a problem. I am able to have a radio shown on page on file clear action, but side bar remains and text area and button isn't shown again by default. Pls find my code below:

code to get 1-3 above.

```
import streamlit as st
    placeholder = st.empty()
    # Defining title Font styling
    with placeholder.container():
        input_option = st.radio("**Choose input option**", ('Enter Text', 'Upload Document'), horizontal= True)
    
    if input_option == "Enter Text":
        with st.container():
            text = st.text_area("**Enter text content to tag:**", height= 300, key= "text")
            button = st.button("Submit")
            if text or button:
                response = get_text_content(text)
                st.info(f'response: {",".join(response)}')
    else:
        uploaded_file = st.sidebar.file_uploader(label ="Upload a File", key= "uploaded_file", label_visibility= 'collapsed')
        print(f'Uploaded file: {st.session_state.uploaded_file}')
        if uploaded_file is not None:
            display_pdf(uploaded_file)
            placeholder.empty()
```